# Fetching YT video, channel or none

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, match

Given a url list, how can I divide it to 3 sum lists?

one for YT videos, second for YT channels, third for all the rest?

```
const paragraph1 = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsjeEt1ZpqQ';
const regex1 = /www.youtube.com/(\c*)(watch?v=)?<videoId>[A-Z,0-9])/gi;

const paragraph2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKqFqiCe1dCUxRe0_YNZ6gg';                                 
const regex2 = /www.youtube.com/channel/?<channelId>[A-Z,_,0-9])/gi;

const found = paragraph1.match(regex1);
console.log(found);
// expected output: Array ["T", "I"]

const found = paragraph2.match(regex2);
console.log(found);
```

Tried to sandbox on this [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: 1) https://regex101.com/r/MpoNQs/1, 2) https://regex101.com/r/MpoNQs/2 and 3) https://regex101.com/r/MpoNQs/3 ?

Comment: Thanks, can you add this as an answer?
Can we unite them into one match phrase?

Comment: If you need to get three different groups, doesn't it make more sense to use different regexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are planning to split some URL string list into three different parts, you can use three different patterns:

```
www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(?<videoId>\S+)
www\.youtube\.com\/channel\/(?<videoId>\S+)
www\.youtube\.com(?!\/(?:channel\/|watch\?v=))\S*
```

See [regex #1](https://regex101.com/r/MpoNQs/1), [regex #2](https://regex101.com/r/MpoNQs/2) and [regex #3](https://regex101.com/r/MpoNQs/3) demos. Note you need an ECMAScript 2018+ compliant JavaScript environment for the named capturing groups to work. Also, see the dots are escaped everywhere they denote literal dots.

The patterns mean

- `www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=` - a literal `www.youtube.com/watch?v=`
  string
- `(?<videoId>\S+)` - Group "videoId": one or more non-whitespace chars
- `www\.youtube\.com\/channel\/(?<videoId>\S+)` - a literal `www.youtube.com/channel/` string and then Group "videoId" capturing one or more non-whitespace chars
- `www\.youtube\.com(?!\/(?:channel\/|watch\?v=))\S*` - `www.youtube.com` string and then a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right, there is a `/` char, then `channel/` or `watch?v=`, and then zero or more non-whitespace chars are consumed.

If you plan to use the patterns agains some mark-up text, make sure you subtract the mark-up chars from the `\S` pattern, that is, change it into a negated character class with a reverse shorthand, `[^\s]`, and add the chars after `\s`. Say, if the links are inside double quotes, put `"` there, `[^\s"]`.